web locate me button is not working on android webview
we have a web app that showing an ezri map with locate me button, the button is working on the web browser, but its not working on the android web view, also the location permission is enabled, see code below:
the error we get on the CONSOLE:
INFO:CONSOLE(285)] "Error: User denied Geolocation
the location permission enabled:
requestPermissions(
    activity,
    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
    1)

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun LoadWebView(url: String) {
    MyTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            Column {
               
                val state = rememberWebViewState(
                    url
                )
                val loadingState = state.loadingState
                if (loadingState is LoadingState.Loading) {
                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                        progress = loadingState.progress,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                }
                WebView(
                    state, onCreated = {
                        it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                        it.settings.allowContentAccess = true
                        it.settings.allowFileAccess = true
                        it.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                        it.settings.useWideViewPort = true
                        it.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                        it.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically=true
                        it.settings.databaseEnabled = true
                        it.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
                        it.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
                        it.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
                            override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(
                                origin: String,
                                callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback
                            ) {
                                callback.invoke(origin, true, false)
                            }
                        }
                    }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
            }


        }
    }
}

